# Lock record and release lock after user action from jsp pages

Tags: java, javascript

I have a requirement where in my page i have table having list of records.
When user clicked on one record, record should be locked and someone else with old view of overview screen tries to click on the record, it shows a pop up with a message 'Sorry this record is in progress'.

I thought of adding a column in db table where i will make entry say 'In prodress' when someone click and see particular record and later when he close that record i will update that column with say 'Free'. But i have a issue here if somebody select record and close browser directly without closing properly and releasing that lock in that case nobody will be able to see that record.

Please let me know if there is any other way to implement this or how we can implement this in above mention case.

Condition 1 : Two user login at same time record is available to both in normal color say green. User 1 click on record and start editing. In this case there should be some kind of lock so that if user two tries to open same record he will get pop up message 'In progress'.

Condition 2 : User 1 login and see record in green color. Then user 2 login and see same record in grey color. Now he should not be able to click that record.

Comment: You could time out locks after X hours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is exactly why it is usually not done that way. If you really have a hard lock on the record, your best options is to have some kind of timeout. How long the timeout is, depends on your application. Have your client refresh the lock regularly, and you can make the timeout shorter.

A better solution might be not to lock at all, but to check whether someone has already changed the data before saving your changes. This is usually done using a timestamp or version number in the record to be updated. The concept to look for is "optimistic locking".

However, this only works if possible conflicts are relatively improbable. Call center workers updating customer records are a typical case, since it is hardly ever the case that two call center places talk to the same customer at the same time. If it ever happens, one of them will get an error, and has to re-load he data and make the changes again.